# Why is C++ known as 'premature optimizaton'?

Tags: c++, optimization

"Programming in C++ is premature optimization"

Why <strike>does everyone</strike> do some people say this?

Comment: Not everyone says that, I don't.

Comment: People are lazy or can't learn the language to use it effectively.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: First time I heard that

Comment: I second Mahmoud Hossam and Loki Astari. I certainly don't say that, and honestly this is the first time I've heard anybody say that.

Comment: @YannisRizos, that blog post is rather a praise for C++.

Comment: Because they are premature PC programmers? I mainly work with embedded systems. The language used in 90% of the applications is C. Alternatives are assembler, or in rare cases C++ or Ada. Java, C#, Python etc do not exist.

Comment: @SK-logic rant: to talk in a noisy, excited, or declamatory manner -- I meant more the noisy, excited part (I'm using rant for praises, anything that just opinionated) ... But good catch, I wrote that in a hurry, rewrote it...

Comment: @ChuckTesta I've found [one blog post](http://c0de517e.blogspot.com/2008/06/c-is-premature-optimization.html) that discusses the quote (more or less). Feel free to add the link to your question. One random blog not a citation makes, of course, but it's better than none.

Comment: That's a silly phrase, that's what it is. I have to go now, time to debug another segmentation fault in my C++ code.

Comment: This is like taking two cargo-cult arguments and blending them together. It is more stupid than the sum of the stupidness of the two.

Comment: Sounds like the rantings of one of those deranged fools that thinks Python is a useable language.  ;-)  ;-)

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/35987/why-do-so-many-people-dislike-c

Answer (score 37):

People often say this (somewhat tongue-in-cheek, in my experience) as a dig against C++ as a choice of language.  People typically choose C++ because it is, in most cases, faster than an alternative like Python or Java.  However, most of the time, the additional speed gained is not really needed.  When a person says "Programming in C++ is premature optimization" they are saying that you could have programmed your application in some other language, been done much faster, then if you needed to make some part of your code really fast, you could simply code that part in C++ and call that routine from the other language.

Comment: Agreed with your interpretation, although since it is entirely possible in some cases to use a language that simply does not perform well enough to suit the task, I would say that it's not always premature optimization, but in fact a necessary optimization.

Comment: I'd also argue that you have to consider the costs of using C++, which in my experience are not dramatically reduced from Java or C# or Python at all.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to mention the fact that if some part of the code needed to be made fast, then that and only that part could have been coded in C++. It is sufficient to just say that at the time of choosing which language to code in, you obviously did not know whether any part of the program would turn out to be performing below spec, so the choice of a quote - fast - unquote language at the expense of a more productive language was entirely unjustified to begin with.

Comment: There are other reasons to program in C++, as opposed to, say, Java.  In some ways, it's a more expressive (as well as clunkier) language.  RAII is a very nice way to handle resources in general, and the template system is very powerful, to name two examples.

Answer (score 22):

Because they don't know how to program in C++.

Generally speaking, such people simply don't understand how to program safely (and quickly) in C++ and suggest that doing so takes up an inordinate amount of time or somesuch rubbish. If it really was significantly slower, then people would only do it to make their programs run faster, as C++ is easily the fastest mainstream language. That would make it an optimization- "I'd rather program in C#, but I have to use C++ because it's faster.", and usually premature because most optimizations are.

However, this is usually ignorant. C++ hasn't been a hassle to program in since `shared_ptr` and `std::vector` were invented.

Edit: Sorry, I wasn't sufficiently clear. I forget when speaking to non-C++'ers how little they generally know about the language, as I usually just stick in the C++ channel on SO. First, `shared_ptr` is hardly the only smart pointer, I use `unique_ptr` a lot more often, and Boost has more. Second, garbage collection is *nothing* like `shared_ptr`. Try to garbage collect GPU memory, or a file handle, or a database connection, or an HWND. Good luck. Third, the customizability of `shared_ptr` is vastly above what you can get from a garbage collected system. Recently, I replaced my memory allocations with a memory arena allocator that I wrote myself. It was like, a hundred lines of code and an hour to test. But I didn't have to re-write a single line of my shared_ptr code, because I just dropped in a custom deleter and it just worked. Try replacing your allocator or inventing a new smart pointer in C# or Java and tell me how long that takes. Oh wait, if you look at `using`, then even special language power can't make another kind of resource management work in C#. If garbage collection doesn't suit your needs, then you're screwed. That's not my definition of a higher-level language.

Now, I'll be the first to admit that I'm not on the *cutting edge* of languages like Python, Java, or C#. But as far as I know, Java and C# have nothing as strong as templates. Java's generics are hardly good for *anything*, and C#'s aren't that much better. For example, I use an expression template to automatically generate a finite state machine. I've never seen anything like that. If I was coding in Java, I'd have to code it manually.

Comment: C++ is easily the fastest mainstream language? Really? How can it be faster than C?? And also, I heard that Java these days the JVM has been so much optimized that it's really difficult to say that C++ is "faster" anymore than Java, right?

Comment: @ChuckTesta: C isn't mainstream. Even if it was, it's horrendous unsafety would easily disqualify it from useful comparison. And also, C++'s templates and inline functions *can* be faster than C. And whoever you heard that from was a moron, or uninformed, or potentially both.

Comment: The last part of your comment you're referring to the Java part right?

Comment: @Chuck: Yeah. There's no way that Java is faster than C++ in the general case- by a considerable margin.

Comment: Well, I heard the gap is closing, and possibly marginal in many cases, that it's "not fair to automatically say C++ is 'faster' than Java"........

Comment: @DeadMG: Very good answer. And C++ is faster than C because you get superfast algorithms and containers for free. std::set find, and that saves one day of C coding, yet from performance standpoint it's as fast, with different constant factor, but the general complexity will be the same.

Comment: @Coder - Can you do everything in C++ that you can with C? Because I heard that C basically has the power of assembly (complete control of the machine) while I was wondering if the same could be said - and done efficiently - in C++

Comment: @ChuckTesta: Yes, C++ is pretty much a superset of C, which allows for some handy shortcuts, although backfires with a requirement of greater knowledge. You can write C with templates and that alone will save you weeks of coding.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is really nice compared to raw pointers, but it is still a hassle compared to what languages like Java and Python use. My feeling on C++ is that you spend a lot of effort trying to make it into a nicer language. Eventually, you realize you should just be using a nicer language.

Comment: @Winston Ewert: I don't find `shared_ptr` any harder to use than references in Java. What makes you think they're more of a hassle? I actually find C++ semantics make a lot of sense. Its syntax could be better, but it can't because it has to be somewhat compatible with C.

Comment: The thing that makes `shared_ptr` a hassle is the fact that it only recently became standardized.  So there's 20 years' worth of C++ code that uses home-grown versions of `shared_ptr` -- or doesn't use smart pointers at all.

Comment: @Insilico, for one, its more of a hassle because you have to explicitly use it. In other languages you get everything `shared_ptr` offers on every pointer automatically without effort. There are a few cases such as reference cycles or getting a pointer to `this` where other languages make the task easier. So the shared_ptr stuff is just easier and tends to work a little bit better in other languages.

Comment: @Insilico, having said that, there is a lot to like about C++ semantics. The fact that something like `shared_ptr` is possible means that C++ is an utterly amazing language. There are some features there I wish I had in another languages. But in the end, I don't find it a very productive language.

Comment: -1 for the fact it calls people who find C++ less productive "ignorant" and says "they don't know how to program C++" and calls their opinion "rubbish".

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Garbage collection and `shared_ptr` have nothing at all in common. For example, try to garbage-collect a file, database connection, or GPU memory.

Comment: @dan04: Boost's has been mature for a considerable period of time.

Comment: shared_ptr (reference counting) in general kills performance in multithreaded programs since 1) counters have to be updated atomically [lot more overhead than simple inc/dec], which 2) generates unnecessary cache coherency traffic (also read about false sharing).

Comment: "C isn't mainstream?" Check what technologies the whole internet is built on. Or what is used to write iOS apps (ObjC, unlike C++, is a strict superset of C.).

Comment: @zvrba: Most C++ memory management is containers or `unique_ptr`, not `shared_ptr`. Most of the time, you just don't need shared ownership. And secondly, Objective-C code does not count as C anymore than C++ does, nor does code written in languages implemented in C.

Comment: You can't write ObjC without knowing C. So, yes, it counts.

Comment: Can you please take this conversation to [chat]. If there's any useful information can it be edited into the answer. These comments are likely to be deleted.

Answer (score 9):

Well, that's because programming in C++ *does not* magically give you any performance boost over, for example, Java. You need to do it *very well*, and doing that in C++ is definitely not an easy task. Also time consuming and programmer's time is not cheap...

Comment: It does, the start-up time is 5x faster, you don't need a stupid JRE and C++ apps are faster even for dumb implementations. And if you optimize the app, you can get a huge performance quite easily, 7x+. And it's not hard to optimize C++ apps. Choose the correct type of container, call vector::reserve, and you're set.

Comment: Then show me 5x or 7x performance improvement with C++ over Java on http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/ without a lot of totally unreadable, carefully crafted code, as you said it could be gained quite easily. You can even contribute such program to beat "stupid JRE".

Comment: Google helps there: https://days2011.scala-lang.org/sites/days2011/files/ws3-1-Hundt.pdf There is even more than 7x fold increase in performance, and optimizations performed seem rather ordinary to me, as a C/C++ developer. But Java/.NET developers often complain because in C++ you have to think a little, not just write. Algorithm.Factory.Do.CoolSort

Comment: Well, you *can* find such example, but on shootout you deal with couple more usual problems... And see if there really is such difference. You said, you can easily get huge performance on every program - so just do it and post it on shootout. I think you rather know your answer upfront, because you are C++ developer (so you are very smart by definition ;)) not like these Java not thinking idiots using stupid JRE. Please rethink quality of your arguments...

Comment: Ok, sorry, it wasn't meant to imply that Java or .NET developers are not smart. What I meant is: - "JRE/.NET framework is stupid", you have to install it for most apps, it's bloated, bugs with constant updates, drops goo over whole PC, has slow startup times and large memory footprint. People that imply that Java is as fast as C/C++ usually write their regular implementation and expect the VM to do magic while not even bothering to think about complexities and efficient memory layout, algorithms. There is no way Java can beat readable C/C++ if C/C++ coder is not a beginner.

Comment: That said, I do not think that C++ is "evil" in any way. It can be useful, and *can* deliver mind blazing performance, but I disagree that it is automatically/easily 7x faster than Java. Btw, I very like the D language which seems to me as much more cleanly designed C++.

Comment: Also, I cannot agree on such buggy/bloated frameworks. For example, I had very good experience with Mono (I only code on Linux), which is coded in C. I also noted that Mono's memory footprint is much less than Java's (maybe because it has structs which can be in-structure (or stack) allocated?). Mono's JIT is however far from being state-of-the-art these days, for example it has poor register allocator. But, well, it should improve some day ;)

Comment: Moreover, look up Herb Stutter presentation on C++ and efficiency, in most data-centers the largest expense is not the development time, but the time applications spend running, .NET and Java looses by a huge margin there, 7x+ times the electricity/hardware/cooling costs x24x356 and you have a huge data-centers that costs millions simply wasted.

Comment: I agree. I did not say, that Java is good for everything and C++ isn't good at all. If largest expense is applications running time, then definitely go for C++ ;) But the datacenters is not the whole world.

Comment: "Bloat" is a matter of perspective.  If you're writing an OS kernel, it's "bloat" to have a database client, HTTP library, XML parser, or Unicode support in your language's standard library.  But if you're writing web services, these things are pretty darn *essential*.

Comment: Sorry. I don't find writing C++ any harder than writing perl or python. It may take a lot longer to learn not only the language but where to find the appropriate libraries but once you have passed the curve it is no more difficult to use.

Comment: I just noticed that 4 people upvoted 7x comment ;) I am pretty sure there soon be a lot of 7x faster than Java, easily written programs on shootout ;)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used C++ in a long time (and never templates), so this is from memory based on other questions on Programmers.SE and on StackOverflow:

Templates are handled at compile time, and C++ allows you do do some crazy tricks with complicated ones.

Because they're handled at compile time instead of runtime, all that execution is "optimized" away, leading to compiled code that could in some cases be *faster* than C, because the optimizations done are complicated and hard to to by hand.

And it's "premature" optimization because this is done before any testing for speed ;)

If anyone with experience wants to add/fix what I remember, please do.  Don't just downvote.

Comment: Very true, +1. I agree.